# Visual Studio Code Missing some syntax highlighting in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I recently just started messing around with nodeJS in Visual Studio code and I noticed that it is missing some syntax highlighting compared to what I was seeing via screenshots and videos. I am not sure what I am missing. tsd has been downloaded and I do have intellisense for nodeJS things, but the highlighting is missing.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Please see the related issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1849). We since uploaded new dark and light themes to the extension gallery so that you can get more colors back.